# Is it possible to show the user's page if there's no posts by the user in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, posts

I got a wordpress problem and couldn't find a perfect solution.

There's an attorneys-at-law website I built for my client by using wordpress.
I apply the function of "users" to add several lawyers, and each one has their own page.

But I found if there's no posts posted by the user, it will diagnose that the user doesn't exist and jump to another user's page.

One of the solutions came to my mind is that I asked every lawyer to have posts on the site, but in fact they couldn't write so many articles before the website go online.

So I need to solve this problem for now, please kindly help me if anyone knows some tricks, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your users are basically the authors. Here is a similar question with solution.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/show-author-archive-pages-for-authors-with-no-posts

Comment: Thank you for your help! The question seems the same as mine, but I don't know how and where to apply the codes in the author page since I am not familiar with php codes.  Should I provide my codes for you to check the details? Or could you teach me what should I put in my codes?

Comment: If your theme has an author.php file, you need to modify that file. The link contains a sufficient description on how to edit the file. Let me know if you find this file and able to comprehend it.

Comment: Hi Varun, thank you for your kindly help! I created the theme by myself which is also my first time to make a theme.  I am familiar with html/css, but it took me a lot of time to make a theme coz there's php and wordpress rules that I've never learned before.
http://codepad.org/sZkYQbnq
Sorry I am not able to comprehend the file, so I upload my author.php file to the codepad, could you please check the code and guide me how to modify the file? (In this file I also applied the plugins of custom-fields-pro and wpml.)  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @TerryChan Hi, I went through your file. This is a lot more complex than I expected. Apologies as I might not be able to run through this in my limited time I have.

Comment: Hi Varun, I understand your consideration, thanks anyway for your great inspiration, I will try to find a proper way to solve the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What if the post in every page is the attorney's profile? Just a suggestion.